# Ensure that two tuple arguments have the same number of elements

Tags: typescript

I want something like this:

```js
function test(a: something, b: something) { ... }

test([1,2], [3,4])   // This is ok
test([1,2], [3,4,5]) // This is not ok. Arguments have different length. Should throw error
test([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]) // This is ok too, the length itself doesn't matter, only equality
```

Is it possible somehow in TypeScript? I would like to change the `something` type to implement this, not during runtime.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

1. Make TypeScript treat the arguments as tuples by saying `T extends unknown[] | [unknown]`
2. Put an extra constraint on `b`: `T & { length: T['length'] }`

```
declare function test<T extends unknown[] | [unknown]>(a: T, b: T & { length: T['length'] }): void;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAeAFXhAA9DVgj40BrVHAd1QG0BdeAH3hcWbTjwB8ACigAueOQA08AEZzKAMngBveBBCoA5hgAWargHI9hk%20b4BfAJRyAbjizAA3ACgvhEpK4ARgUAJh4lLgBmBQAWHgd4RIB6JPljLEYM%20BxmX2IMAOD4EKVo%20BilAFZwoQA2JQB2JQAOJQBOJUCABnj4FLSsrJyCHBwlEwQrI2N4LAwiEAhEeGAcYlRzDHgAWygMQhglPAgATyoAR2QoCDmTnz8CoKUwiLKK%20GqE-vJ0zMY2LY5AB08AAgjADMhtvp5vBjFBnAhgFhEIgQHBUFspiYQQBlYw4ZAQYAEYwwDhUGDkmA%20IA)

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up using something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFOA7A1hg9gdwwG0BdKAHyiMxwIxICgATCAY0QEMAnaAM01bAAlrgxRgEAM7AAPDACMUCAA8JGJpNgJkAGlgAmJaojrN8JBAB8ACg4AuWPL0AjBzEMAyKAG8oyDADmwAAWbvJEAOT+QcERZAC+AJQOAG64QkwA3AwMEtLWRE76JHpEAMw6ACwkiVB1APT1sMFCmq1QuFi5UsAFTlD6ehVQlXoArCVUAGx6AOx6ABx6AJx68gAMNVCNze3tneK4uHoh0NEhUELAkhCIvFBMuFIYEcBQALYcwBJceqKIICUAEc4BxEFcQDk8r1CnpiqVhqMoBNajsYC02po8G9OgA6KAAQS4ATg7xM1ygwQ4KWgTCEvF4EB4GDe52C+IAysFcHBEExxMEuAQlFwhVwoT0+nDJkQAEQcWV6WXOWU1IA). However, this causes elements to fail, not whole tuples

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by *causes elements to fail*? By the way, I created a different version that works with heterogeneous lists. Find it here: https://gist.github.com/karol-majewski/8db2d67b4220ce0e45078286168241e0#file-zip-heterogeneous-ts